# Android -> Facebook login without a dialog?

Tags: android, facebook

I've been following a tutorial from *[Using Facebook SDK in Android development, Part 1](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1)* and *[Using Facebook SDK in Android development, Part 2](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2)* to create a Facebook login. But there, once I press the login-button, a standard login-dialog pops out... Yet, I want it to login with already set credentials, without that dialog, such as a login function that takes in "email" and "password" and returns, say, the user's screen name.

What do you think would be the best way to do that?

I searched the web long and hard and everywhere it says that you can't get rid of the standard login dialog, BUT if we look at the Messenger application, Belgium, man!, it does have a custom login screen! How did they do that? :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is better for you to follow the official Facebook's instructions because Facebook changes the API all the time, so even if some post on the Internet had really good tutorials or guides... they get "deprecated" really fast.

The updated information is always here:

- [General information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)
- [Android tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

You can get a working example at *[Facebook SDK for Android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)* (GitHub).

I've followed those instructions, and I achieved signup and you do not need to login again (you'll need to re-login only if the token you obtained at signup is not valid anymore or your user deliberately unlinked your application from Facebook).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yet is it possible to make even the first time login without that dialog? I've already made my own very cute dialog where the user would enter his credentials.

Comment: @user296516: as of now u cant make use of custom fb login other than ( fb webview dialog or the official facebook android app login)