# Using forms to connect to Facebook in Android?

Tags: android, facebook

While using the Facebook [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) for Android, I realise Facebook uses their own dialogs with forms so the user can enter their information.

Is there a way to use my own forms and send the data to Facebook to authenticate? Or do I have to use theirs? If so, is that the same case for uploading pictures, posting on your wall, comment, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about uploading pictures, but I ran into the same problem some time before with the forms and after a lot of research reached the conclusion that you have to use their forms. The only application AFAIK that uses custom Facebook login on Android is Facebook for Android (official application).

You might be able to figure out a way by tracing the URL that is being used by Facebook for authentication, but those sorts of hacks won't be reliable as Facebook may change the API on you. It sucks, yeah.

Here is some more information, Stack Overflow question *[Android -> Facebook login without a dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579592/android-facebook-login-without-a-dialog)*.